# TYPO3: extension: store configuration for external system

Tags: php, typo3, extension-methods

I'm implementing an extension that should be able use external services (outside of TYPO3).
It is also important that a part of business logic of my extension is available as a scheduler task - that means it could be called just as a PHP Class.

What is the typical/best place (way?) to store configuration (ip, port and so on) for such external services?

I've implemented extension's options with FlexForms ([tutorial here](https://wiki.typo3.org/Extension_Development,_using_Flexforms)). But these are obviously unvisible when called as scheduler task.

Is it possible to store configuration in `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXT']['extConf']['myvendor']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. Extension configuration is the right place, assuming all the websites in your TYPO3 installation or all the schedulers if you want to run multiple will share the same configuration.

[TYPO3 manual page](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ExtensionArchitecture/ConfigurationOptions/Index.html)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for link with docu.